# (Rails) Some users getting paid twice when withdrawing money from their balance to bank account. Can't reproduce

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, payment-gateway, balanced-payments

In my app a worker can build up a credit balance in their account and withdraw it to their bank account as they see fit. There is a `MoneyController::withdraw` action that calls a `.withdraw_funds` method on the `current_worker` which makes a call to the Balanced Payments API and credits their bank account if the `amount` they've requested to withdraw is <= the amount in their balance. a `Transaction` is created, attached to the worker's `Account`, that lists the amount that was subtracted from their balance and credited to their bank account.

Recently something has been happening where this controller action gets hit and the whole process is taking place twice, even though the request is supposed to be rejected if the balance is empty. The withdrawal happens twice and two transactions are generated with the same or very close timestamp. However, it only happens for some workers, and I can't reproduce the error on the development or staging servers. I was hoping someone could give me some advice as to how to proceed with debugging this. Here is the relevant code:

```
MoneyController
  def withdraw
    if current_worker.withdraw_funds((params[:amount].to_d*100).to_i, params[:bbank])
      redirect_to worker_money_path, notice: "Successfully withdrew $#{params[:amount]}"
    else
      redirect_to worker_money_path, alert: "Failed to withdraw funds. Please contact us for assistance."
    end
  end
```

/

```
worker.rb

  def withdraw_funds(amount, bbank_id)
    bcust = self.get_balanced
    bbank = Balanced::BankAccount.fetch("/bank_accounts/#{bbank_id}")
    if bbank and (bbank.customer.id == bcust.id)
      puts "bank belongs to worker"
      if self.account.balance >= amount
        res = bbank.credit(amount: amount)
        self.account.debit(amount)
        Transaction.create(amount: amount, tag: 'cashout', source_id: self.account.id, destination_id: nil, balanced_id: res.id)
        return true
      else
        puts "worker #{self} doesn't have #{amount} in account"
        return false
      end
    else
      puts "bank does not belong to worker"
      return false
    end
  end
```

If the worker's balance contains $50 and two requests are made for $50, the first should succeed and then the second should fail because the balance is now $0 (hence `if self.account.balance >= amount`).

I was able to look through the logs of the development server as well and find the logs for when this happened:

```
Started POST "/money/withdraw" for 68.119.221.188 at 2014-11-05 13:56:41 -0500
Processing by MoneyController#withdraw as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"x5olIpvJf2K37lYRJypIIHYNhAdZUm1ptill13w9Evw=", "amount"=>"48.50", "bbank"=>"BA2...", "commit"=>"Withdraw"}
Started POST "/money/withdraw" for xx.xxx.xxx.xxx at 2014-11-05 13:56:46 -0500
Processing by MoneyController#withdraw as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"x5olIpvJf2K37lYRJypIIHYNhAdZUm1ptill13w9Evw=", "amount"=>"48.50", "bbank"=>"BA2...", "commit"=>"Withdraw"}
Redirected to http://myapp.com/money
Completed 302 Found in 4467.9ms (ActiveRecord: 54.7ms)
Started GET "/worker/money" for xx.xxx.xxx.xxx at 2014-11-05 13:56:50 -0500
Processing by Worker::MoneyController#index as HTML
Redirected to http://myapp.com/money
Completed 302 Found in 9099.1ms (ActiveRecord: 69.6ms)
```

I notice in the logs that both requests have the same authenticity token but am not sure what else to take away from them. I thought it could be as simple as the worker clicking the "Withdraw" button multiple times but in my attempts to recreate the issue in development and staging that never caused the problem. The requests were just queued and the succeeding requests always caused the proper response that the balance was empty.

***EDIT*** I set up a test scenario on the production server and was able to reproduce the problem by clicking the Withdraw button multiple times. Anyone have any idea as to why this would happen in Production but not in Development or Staging? Could connection speed have anything to do with it?

Comment: Hi. Is the request fired by ajax or, in general, by javascript?

Comment: No, it is an HTML request

Comment: Can you please paste the html for the form and if there is any existing relative event handler (in javascript or jQuery)?

Comment: I added an update to the question. Somehow I was able to reproduce the problem by clicking the button multiple times in Production. The same kind of test did not reproduce the problem in Development/Staging.

Comment: I'll write one possible answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not posting client code, I could suggest you put some kind of lock to `Worker` so as he can only have one running transaction at a time... something like `in_process:boolean` and `process_start:timestamp` (both combined).

So, when you start a transaction, you make sure that `in_process` is `false` and set it to `true`, also modifying the `process_start` (put there for accidental locks, for example, assume a lock active if `in_process && process_start>(Time.now - 10.minutes)`.

After the process is finished, you set the `in_process` flag back to false.

This way, only one process per user can be active.

Of course, if we have some `html`, this will probably not be necessary, but it's good practice to have business (controller) logic behind processes that involve money anyhow.

EDIT: Perhaps it would also be good idea to keep the `Worker` locked for some seconds after the transaction has ended.

Comment: Thank you for this recommendation. I will give it a shot. My current solution is just to use javascript to disable the button after it has been clicked but front-end restrictions, as you point out, aren't as secure as implementing some kind of controller logic. I have never heard of these process/transaction locks. Do you know of any documentation that I could read for further info?

Comment: My answer is custom logic, but you can search google "rails transaction lock"  to find stuff... but, as far as I know, none of the existing solutions provide for a brief-after-commit-lock-time. You could use for instance active record's `lock` method or `transaction` blocks